# Are variables in the function within a class shared between all other functions enclosed in that class in Python?

Tags: python, function, variables, namespaces, scope

I know class attributes are shared and can be accessed by all functions enclosed in the same class, but my question is what about variables enclosed in functions in a class?

I'm trying to create a GUI and my class is made up only of functions.

```
class Application():

    def func_a(self):
        self.x = Entry(text="My entry text")

    def func_b(self):
        self.x.config(width=100)
```

Can this work? Will the `self.x` variable in the first function be referred to by `func_b` if they're in the same class? How does Python deal with variables in different functions all enclosed in the same class? I suppose they will be shared but I have no idea.

Comment: why don't you test it on your own?

Comment: I could, but I'd much prefer that some kind soul would explain how Python works in this context so I know what to do when dealing with classes.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can this work? Will the self.x variable in the first function be referred to by func_b if they're in the same class?

Absolutely. But since the variable `x` is created only in `func_a`, it should have been called before `func_b` is called. Otherwise you will get an error.

> How does Python deal with variables in different functions all enclosed in the same class? I suppose they will be shared

Since the instance variables are specific to the instances they are defined in, they will be available to all the methods in the class. In your case, when you do

```
self.x = ...
```

you are actually creating an attribute called `x`, in the current instance referred by `self`. So, if you invoke `func_b` with the same instance, it will work fine. For example,

```
# Create an instance
app = Application()

# Call `func_a` to create `x` in `app`
app.func_a()

# Check if it is present
print(app.x)

# Call `func_b` and now it should not fail
app.func_b()
```

**Edit:** As Gabriel mentions in the comments, try to create the instance variables in the `__init__` (constructor) itself, so that you don't have to worry about the order of function calls.

Comment: To complete the answer : In order to make attribute accessible for all functions without taking care of the call order, you want to initialize them in the `__init__` function.

Comment: No prob. In fact, as the constructor (`__init__`) is called when you create the object, it's the very first method you call on the object. So what you explained also applies.